# Finding $\lim\limits_{a\to 1}\int_{0}^{a}x\ln(1-x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Calculate
>   $$\lim_{a\to 1}\int_{0}^{a}x\ln(1-x)dx, a\in (0,1)$$

I calculate the integral but when I calculate the limit I get $\ln(0)$ and the limit should be $-\frac{3}{4}$.

How to approach the exercise in other way?

Comment: How are you approaching the integral?

Comment: By parts.I take f(x)=ln(1-x) so f'(x)=1/(1-x) and g'(x)=x so g(x)=x^2/2

Comment: @DaniVaja You should have $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: That will yield $$\int_0^a \dfrac{x^2}{2(1-x)}$$

How do you handle that?

Comment: I get $\frac{-a^{2}-2a-ln(a-1)^{2}}{4}$

Comment: I use substitution of $u=1-x, du=-dx, x=1-u$ to get

$$\int_0^a \dfrac{(1-u)^2}{2u} du = \int_0^a \Bigg( \dfrac{1}{2u} - 1 + \dfrac{u}{2} \Bigg) du$$

This will result in $\dfrac{1}{2} ln|2(1-x)| -1 +x +\dfrac{1}{4}(1-x)^2$

Comment: @DaniVaja Write it instead as $-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-a) - \frac{a^2}{4}-\frac{a}{2}$. Now you have to combine the $\ln(1-a)$ term with the rest (i.e., $f(x)g(x)$ evaluated at $x=a$) before taking the limit.

Comment: My whole expression is 

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 1} \dfrac{a^2}{2} \ln|1-a| - \dfrac{1}{2} \ln|2(1-a)| -a -\dfrac{1}{4}(1-a)^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}\ln|2| +\dfrac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left.\lim_{a \to 1^{\Large -}}
\int_{0}^{a}x\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,&
\lim_{a \to 1^{\Large -}}\bracks{%
{1 \over 2}\,a^{2}\ln\pars{1 - a} -
\int_{0}^{a}\pars{{1 \over 2}\,x^{2}}{-1 \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{a \to 1^{\Large -}}\bracks{%
{1 \over 2}\,a^{2}\ln\pars{1 - a} -
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{a}\pars{1 + x - {1 \over 1 - x}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{a \to 1^{\Large -}}\bracks{%
{1 \over 2}\,a^{2}\ln\pars{1 - a} -
{1 \over 2}\,a - {1 \over 4}\,a^{2} -
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{1 - a}}
\\[5mm] = &\ \bbx{-\,{3 \over 4}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DaniVaja You’re welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s another approach:

$$\lim_{a\to 1}\int_{0}^{a}x\log(1-x)dx=-\lim_{a\to 1}\int_{0}^{a}\sum_{n\ge 1}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{n}}dx=-\lim_{a\to 1}\sum_{n\ge1}{\int_{0}^{a}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{n}}}dx=-\lim_{a\to 1}\sum_{n\ge 1}{\frac{a^{n+2}}{n(n+2)}}$$
$$=-\sum_{n\ge 1}{\frac{1}{n(n+2)}}=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 1}{\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)}= -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 1}{\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)}$$
$$ =-\frac{1}{2}{\overbrace{\sum_{n\ge 1}{\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}}}^{=1}-\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 1}{\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)}}_{\text{this is 1/2}}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\times 1-\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help!